# Rails parameter from controller can not shown in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using ajax to get user selected date from datepicker, then pass them to controller to calculate the result, then pass the result back to view.

In my **model** I have:

```
def mobile_type_count(name,name1,field, 
    filed1,value, start_time, end_time )
 ........
end
```

**Controller**  analyzer_controller.rb

```
def data

start_time = params[:start_date]?
        Date.parse(params[:start_date]) :Date.iso8601
end_time =  params[:end_date]?
        Date.parse(params[:end_date]) :Date.iso8601

     @iphone =Analyzer.new.
      mobile_type_count('deviceOS','mobileNum','$deviceOS',
                        '$mobileNum','iOS' , start_time , end_time  )
      @android = Analyzer.new.
      mobile_type_count('deviceOS','mobileNum','$deviceOS',
                        '$mobileNum','Android' ,  start_time, end_time )

 end
```

**View**  data.html.erb

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" value="2016-04-11" id="startDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" value="2016-04-13" id="endDate" />
  </div>
    <%=   button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default btn-sm", :id => 'get_data' ) do %>
        Submit

    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="ibox-content">
      <%=  pie_chart({"iphone" => @iphone, "android" => @android}) %>
    </div>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#get_data').click(function(){
        var sd = $('#startDate').val(),
            ed = $('#endDate').val()
    $.ajax({
      url: "/analyzer/data",
      type: "post",
      data: {'start_date' :sd, 'end_date': ed},

      success: function(){
      },
      error:function(){
        alert('Error');
      }
    });
  });
```

when I select date range and click submit button, I get nothing, but when
**I used** `puts` **to test if the selected date has been passed to controller**

```
 <%=  puts  pie_chart({"iphone" => @iphone, "android" => @android}) %>
```

I can get result printed on Terminal,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Chartkick.PieChart("chart-1", {"iphone":[11],"android":[10]}, {});
```

@iphone = [11] @android = [10], which is correct,

when I remove `puts` , then check  the result in browser , @iphone and @android are empty arraies:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Chartkick.PieChart("chart-1", {"iphone":[],"android":[]}, {});
</script>
```

not sure what happened,  hope some one can explain to me a little bit . Thank you

**UPDATED**
here is `the mobile_type_count` method,  but I'm sure the method is fine, otherwise  `<%=  puts  pie_chart({"iphone" => @iphone, "android" => @android}) %>`  wont return any result. The reason why I use `puts` is just for testing, I think the problem is the result (@iphone, @andriod) did not get rendered in the view

```
def mobile_type_count(name,name1,field, filed1,value, start_time, end_time )

date_match = {:$match  => {:created_at => { :$gt =>  start_time , :$lt => end_time  }}}
match = { :$match => {name => value}}
group ={:$group =>{ :_id =>
                         {name => field,
                          name1 => filed1},
                     :count => {:$sum =>1}
}}
group1 = {:$group =>{:_id =>
                          { name => field,
                            name1 => filed1},
                      #:totalCount=> { :$sum => '$count' },
                      :distinctcount => {:$sum => 1}
}}

mobile_usr= collection.aggregate([date_match,match,group,group1])

mobile_usr.map do |m|
  m[:distinctcount]
end
  end
```

Comment: It looks like `mobile_type_count` is returning an empty array. Can you include sample code for the `mobile_type_count` method?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `puts` from the line below. Otherwise you are rendering to your `$stdout`.

```
<%=  puts  pie_chart({"iphone" => @iphone, "android" => @android}) %>
```

Should be:

```
<%=  pie_chart({"iphone" => @iphone, "android" => @android}) %>
```

Comment: I use puts just for testing,  after removing puts it still get nothing

Comment: Then the problem is in your `pie_chart` method. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: `pie_chart` is a method from charkick gem, when I just put actual date : Date.new(2016,4,11) to `mobile_type_count,` the chart can be generated.

Comment: would you mind check out my updated post?  thank you